# does this sentence sound right?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

"I read this novel four times in Arabic and now it’s the English edition turn"

Comment: This question was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
Question lacks evidence of research.
Questions that ask for proofreading of a text are out of scope.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Since the turn "belongs" to the English edition, so to speak, I would indicate the possessive with an apostrophe-s added to "edition."

Also, since the second clause of the sentence is independent (it has a subject, *it*, and a verb, *is*), you need a comma after "Arabic."

So you have:

> I read this novel four times in Arabic, and now it's the English edition's turn.

As far as whether the sentence generally makes sense, I would say yes. It might be a little unconventional to say that an inanimate object (edition) has a "turn," but I think that it's still understandable.

Comment: Better than just understandable, I'd say. *Turn* applied to the English edition has the echoes of the reader pivoting to pick up the new tome and turning its pages.